# Jalali Calendar

Tags: c++, algorithm, time, calendar

Is there any function to **directly** convert Unix Time Stamp (returned by time() [ctime library]) to a struct tm or something that holds the date and time in [Jalali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalali_calendar) format?

And I'm not looking for a way to convert Gregorian to Jalali. I'm looking for an algorithm to convert what time(NULL) returns directly to the Jalali calendar.

Comment: Voted to reopen as the original question (which this was marked as a duplicate of) did not answer this question.

Comment: I would love to see a non-iterative answer such as this one for Gregorian calendars (http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#civil_from_days).  This only converts from a count of days, but it is trivial to convert from count-of-seconds to count-of-days.  With a good algorithm, such a calendar could be easily added to this date/time/timezone library which is designed to have many calendars inter-operate: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've developed a similar algorithm to convert [Julian Day Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) to Solar Hijri (~= Jalali) calendar date. The principles are same: take a reference point in time (in your case 1970-01-01 which is equal to JDN #2440587) and calculate how many years, month and days are past since then. My algorithm is based on Akramis's mean-year calculation which has a good conformance to Official Iranian Calendar (same in near past).

The C implementation is available here:

https://github.com/soroush/libcalendars/blob/dev/lib/src/cl-solar-hijri.c

Note that you can convert unix time to JDN only by adding 2440587 offset. So you will need to:

```
int16_t year;
uint8_t month;
int16_t day;
jdn_to_sh(unix_time + 2440587, &year, &month, &date);
```